# Java enum placement in Interface or Class

Tags: java, class, enums, interface

I am trying to understand enums in Java, but currently can not find a post that explains the question I am asking.

I have a `Person` interface and a `PersonEO` class. Two methods of the Person Interface are setGender and getGender. I would like to hold gender as an enum.

Do I create the enum in the interface and have it get carried over to the class or do I make the enum in the class?

This is currently what I have been trying but can not get the enum to pass over to the class properly and don't really understand how it will flow through the program.

```
public interface Person{
    public enum gender{
    Female,
    Male,
    Unknown;

       private String gender;

       public String getGender(){
       }

       void setGender(){  
       }
}


------------------------------------------------------


public class PersonEO implements Person {
   //Both override methods are not seen as methods from the interface

   @Override
   public String getGender() {
       return gender;
   }

   @Override
   public void setGender() {
       //Not sure how to set the gender from the enum
       this.gender = gender;
   }
}
```

Please show an example.

Comment: Create a member variable Gender and use it in your setters and getters.

Comment: Generally speaking you won't have setters in your enum type.

Comment: In the code for `Person.gender` (should be `Gender`) there was declared an empty method `setGender`. That naming convention implies a missing method argument to pass a value to set. It is unclear what the `setGender` method in `gender` (`Gender`) was intended to do, but whatever it is supposed to set, it is rare to see a setter in an enum. It isn't wrong, exactly, just a little out of kilter with the purpose of an enum constant. They shouldn't hold state normally, because the same constant will be used in many contexts. Also, `Person` was missing a right curly brace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The enum, interface and class are all separate types and should usually be in separate files. Here are some sample definitions:

```
enum Gender {
    MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN;
}

interface Person {
    void setGender(Gender gender);
    Gender getGender();
}

class PersonImpl implements Person {
    private Gender gender;

    @Override
    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Override
    public Gender getGender() {
        return this.gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have setters in the enum. Do you mean the interface?

Comment: Ahhh I see now! Thank you. I was think of enums as a variable instead of a more classifier/segmentation type.

Comment: I was referring to the code in the question, not in the answer. My mistake, now corrected.